# Table and graph position in RMarkdown

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

I am kitting a PDF RMarkdown, however, the graphs nor the tables do not appear in the correct section. How can I stop them from floating so they appear in the right order?

Comment: Hello Maria, welcome to SO. Please post a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: Try `\pagebreak` before a new section

Comment: At the end, I used the following command: ```kable(df) %>% kable_styling(latex_options=c("HOLD_position","scale_down"))```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `out.extra` argument of the code chunk to include `!h`. From https://yihui.org/knitr/options/

> out.extra: (NULL; character) Extra options for figures. It can be an arbitrary string, to be inserted in \includegraphics[] in LaTeX output (e.g., out.extra = 'angle=90' to rotate the figure by 90 degrees), or  in HTML output (e.g., out.extra = 'style="border:5px solid orange;"').

For example,

````
```{r out.extra='!h!}

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(airquality, aes(Temp, Ozone)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess")
```
````

Comment: It is not working. My tables and graphs still appear outside the section where they should be.